# MVC C# Como forçar SSL - too_many_redirects

Tags: c#, mvc, ssl

estou tentando forçar o uso de SSL da minha aplicação MVC WEB.

Já tentei com redirect no global asa, mas ele entra em lopping too_many_redirects.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
  {
      Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
  }
}
```

Como consigo forçar sem cair no problema do redirect?

Comment: Imagino que vc percebeu que o looping too_many_redirects indica que o redirect está sendo feito mesmo quando já está em https, seria o caso de ver se o Context.Request.IsSecureConnection não tem nenhum efeito colateral impedindo a detecção.

Comment: Teste com isso em vez de  Context.Request.IsSecureConnection, apenas para tirar a teima: HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("https://")

Comment: O teste está sendo feito em servidor remoto normal, ou tem algum load balancer, proxy, CloudFlare ou qq coisa do tipo? Se tiver alguma intermediação, as vezes o HTTPS não chega na camada final.

Comment: Servidor remoto normal, ja tentei o Context.Request.IsSecureConnection e ocorre o mesmo, uso CloudFlare sim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Resposta baseada no comment que menciona uso do CloudFlare

Como você usa CloudFlare, a maneira de checar o protocolo é consultar o cabeçalho `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Request.Headers["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] != "https")
  {
      Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
  }
}
```

A explicação é a seguinte: na configuração default, o CloudFlare serve o site para o cliente em HTTPS, mas faz o request para o seu servidor usando HTTP, portanto, causando novo redirecionamento.

Usando o *header* acima, você está identificando o protocolo de fato que o site foi servido ao cliente final.

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco, vou testar e colocar sua resp como correta, obrigado

Comment: @RBoschini na verdade eu tinha posto o exemplo em PHP. Agora converti, mas não testei. Se tiver algum erro de sintaxe me avise que eu ajusto.

Comment: o codigo forca tudo correto, mas na hora que cai em prod, ele fica dando too many redirects, apenas no cloudflare, em um que tenho da locaweb funciona.

Comment: Deveria ser o contrário, na locaweb não era pra funcionar :) O que precisaria ver é quais são os headers que estão chegando de fato na aplicação. O PHP tem o phpinfo(); bom pra debug, nao sei qual seria uma solução equivalente em C#. Mas só pra clarificar, o que acontece é o seguinte: normalmente no CF, a requisição é sempre HTTP, e só "vira" HTTPS quando sai do CF pro cliente, então sua aplicação não pode testar o protocolo real, apenas o cabeçalho do CF. O cliente vai estar acessando HTTPS, mas sai HTTP da máquina da aplicação.

Comment: Vou olhar os headers, obrigado pela ajuda!!!